# Как написать программу которая проверяет лицензию?

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, windows, лицензирование

Как написать программу которая проверяет лицензию? По образу, антивирусов или аналогичных программ, когда вы должны купить лицензию для использования программы. И если срок действия вашей лицензии истек, программа перестает работать.

Интересует код на c++ или любой код на любом языке программирования, или даже простое объяснение алгоритма работы.

Comment: Алгоритм простой (один из возможных): в файле лицензии указывается дата окончания действия. Файл подписывается электронной подписью. Программа проверяет подпись и сверяет текущую дату с указанной в файле. Если подпись невалидна или если текущая дата больше указанной, программа перестает работать.

Comment: Задействовать сервер в интернете который будет проверять валидность/время/другие параметры лицензии  и в зависимости от этого отвечать зашифрованным ключём со значением - да/нет.

Comment: @NewView пока таких возможностей нету.Есть ли другие варианты?

Comment: Проверять локально, но это как правило легко ломается, если это имеет смысл :) и сервер это любая машина с выходом в интернет 24/7 - а софт под сервер вам придеться мастерить самому. Можно еще хешами общаться, брать ип адрес + клентский порт + 100 например, ответ положительный, то же самое, только + 0 - ответ отрицательный, и зашифровывать это при передаче.

Comment: @Yaant Хороший ответ, однако хитрый Вася Пупкин может настроить на своей машине вечное "3 сентября" и перенаправлять любые запросы к NTP на свой сервис.

Comment: @Ainar-G: Ну так любая защита ломается при желании. И сомневаюсь, что польза от программы перевесит возникающие из-за некорректной даты на компьютере проблемы (самая очевидная - со временем все больше и больше сайтов перестанут открываться браузерами, по мере того, как сроки действия их SSL-сертификатов будут выходить из этой даты.) :) А на самом деле у моего алгоритма есть куда большая проблема - ничего не мешает скопировать файл лицензии на произвольное количество компьютеров. :)